# Orfox won't load pages

Tags: orbot, android, website

I cannot access websites on Orfox, .onion or otherwise. The loading bar stops at around 25% and then never moves.

Comment: Your post was not very clear, On Android I believe you need the "OrBot VPN"
utility installed and running. Before using the Orfox browser.

Comment: The VPN feature is experimental, and is not required to use Orfox. Simply having Orbot installed and connected is enough.

Comment: Install Orbot then enable vpn and bridge, select proxy, if still face same problem change the proxy.

Comment: I have had the same issues.. even after switching VPNs and toggling Bridge. I am runnig on Android - Onion search is locating urls but Orfox just hangs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's related, but the same issue seems to happen to me sometines. Simply changing identity works for me, tapping the round arrow in the notification or restarting orbot. Hope this helps